# Unable to run simple program in solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am new in solidity and i am trying to run simple program in "remix ide" but i am getting following errors

```
Gas requirement of function test._feedback is infinite: If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage) Pos: 4:8:



Gas requirement of function test.reply is infinite: If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage) Pos: 6:8:
```

And here is my current code which is not working,How can i do this ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract test {
       string public _feedback;
        function reply(string memory feedback) public pure
        {
           feedback = "Well done!";
           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While running your code in solidity works fine for me..

From your above code, it seems like you want to get input from the user and assign it into storage variable.

Pure Functions in solidity can't able to modify and read storage values.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract test {
       string public _feedback;
        function reply(string memory feedback) public 
        {
           _feedback = feeback;
           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used the **pure modifier** for the reply function and then modified feedback which is wrong!

Pure functions (Functions that have pure keyword) cannot modify or even read the state (state variables of the contract),

If you need more information about view and pure keywords in Solidity, Check the link below:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/solidity-view-and-pure-functions/